# Angular5 data change by Subject does not render Route

Tags: angular

I have a route in which I use Subject.subscription. It is working properly on first time it loads, but if I re-navigate that route, the data is shown in console, but my view is not renders.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this._userService.getMessage()
            .subscribe(user => {
              this._zone.run(() => {
                  this.users = user;
                  console.log(this.users);        
              });                           
            });
}
```

Comment: can you add HTML as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you are navigate to same component the the component refresh wont be happen. so check same code ngOnChanges() or Based on navigation refresh your component.